# „anhängen“ vs. „aufhängen“

Tags: meaning

Ich kann den Unterschied zwischen **anhängen** und **aufhängen** nicht verstehen.

Kann mir das bitte jemand erläutern ?

Answer (score 3):

Hier ein paar Ausdrücke, die du im Alltag gut verwenden kannst:

### Aufhängen

Ich kann

> die Wäsche aufhängen
>
> Weihnachtsschmuck aufhängen
>
> ein Bild aufhängen
>
> das Telefon aufhängen

(etwas altertümlich für *den Hörer auflegen*)

> einen zum Tode Verurteilten aufhängen

(nicht wünschenswert), gleichbedeutend mit dem etwas förmlicheren Ausdruck *jemanden hängen*

> mich daran aufhängen, dass...

(im Sinne von: mich daran stören dass xyz, und dies zum Thema einer kontroversen Diskussion machen. Das ist aber nur umgangssprachlich so zu gebrauchen.)

### Anhängen

Ich kann weiterhin

> den Ladewagen an den Bulldog anhängen
>
> dir etwas anhängen

(dich einer Sache bezichtigen, die du nicht gemacht hast)

> mir jede Menge Schmuck anhängen

(das würde ich aber typischerweise eher machen, wenn ich ein Mädchen wäre)

> einer Sache anhängen, zum Beispiel dem Fußballspiel

(das heißt, ich bin ein Fan davon, oder eben ein **Anhänger**)

### Weitere Wörter aus dieser Familie

Ich kann zum Beispiel auch

> einer verlorenen Liebe **nachhängen**

oder jemandem sagen, der darunter leidet:

> Lass Dir das nicht so nachhängen!

Geht es mir dabei (vorübergehend) schlecht, kann ich sagen

> Ich habe einen **Durchhänger**.

Abends treffe ich mich mit meinen Freunden.

> Zusammen können wir schön **abhängen**

im Sinne von "entspannen", allerdings vor allem, wenn wir Jugendliche sind. Für ältere Leute ist der Ausdruck nicht so passend. Dies ist eine übertragene Bedeutung von *abhängen*. Ansonsten kann man noch

> die Wäsche, den Weihnachtsschmuck und das Bild abhängen

sie also von der Leine, vom Fenster oder von der Wand nehmen, oder

> den Wagen abhängen

und dann mit dem Traktor ohne Anhänger weiterfahren, und zwar möglichst schnell, denn damit kann man gegebenenfalls

> einen Verfolger abhängen

ihm also durch höhere Geschwindigkeit oder geschicktes Manövrieren entwischen. Bin ich dann entwischt und jemand sucht mich, kann er einen **Aushang** machen. Zum Beispiel kann er

> den **Aus**hang **am** Schwarzen Brett **auf**hängen

oder auch

> den Aushang ans Schwarze Brett hängen.

(Ich möchte ehrlich gesagt nicht Deutsch lernen müssen...)

Comment: Obwohl es sehr gute Beispiele (dafür: +1) mit *anhängen* und *aufhängen* gibt, erklärt die Antwort den Unterschied zwischen den Verben nicht ganz klar.

Comment: Ja, das stimmt, es ist keine abstrakte Erklärung dabei. (Siehe dafür gerne Huberts Antwort auf dieser Seite). Ich meine, dass abstrakte Erklärungen nicht immer wirklich hilfreich sind. Manchmal hilft mehr die Pragmatik: Wie werden Wörter in der Praxis eingesetzt. Natürlich gibt es unterschiedliche Lerner-Typen... Bezogen auf die ursprüngliche Frage (Unterschied von *anhängen* und *aufhängen*) braucht man aber wohl unbedingt die konkrete Verwendung, denn ansonsten reduziert sich die Erklärung auf den Unterschied der Präpositionen *an* und *auf*.

Comment: PS: Nimm mal *jemanden aufhängen*: Das erklärt sich nicht mehr über den Unterschied von *an* und *auf*, denn eher hängst du jemanden ***an** einem Baum auf* oder auch ***am** Galgen auf*. Ebenso *jemandem etwas anhängen*: Das könnte genauso gut *jemandem etwas aufhängen* heißen, aber es heißt eben *anhängen*.

Comment: Da hast du Recht. Mit einer abstrakten Erklärung (falls es gibt) muss man auch die Ausnahmen nennen und meistens (weil es manchmal zu viele Ausnahmen gibt) überschatten die Ausnahmen die eigentliche Definition und verkompliziert die Sache mehr.

Comment: Mir gefällt deine Formulierung "Manchmal überschatten die Ausnahmen die eigentliche Definition".

Answer (score 2):

### anhängen

> Heinz **hängt** den Anhänger an sein Auto **an.**

Damit ist gemeint, dass Heinz, hinten an sein Auto einen Beiwagen befestigt, der später vom Auto gezogen werden soll. Weil dieser hinzugefügte Teil ***an*** dem Auto ***hängt***, wird er auch ***Anhänger*** genannt.

Auto und Anhänger befinden sich auf derselben Höhe, das Gewicht des Anhängers lastet (fast) vollständig auf dessen eigenen Rädern. Die Anhängerkupplung hat nicht die Aufgabe die Last des Anhängers zu tragen, sondern eine (in diesem Fall bewegliche) Verbindung zwischen dem Hauptteil (dem Auto) und dem beigefügten Teil (dem Anhänger) zu schaffen.

Das Verb »*anhängen*« kann auch im übertragenen Sinn verwendet werden (»*Jürgen hat Clara ein Kind angehängt.*« oder »*Die wollen mir den Einbruch anhängen.*«) Alle diese Bedeutungen haben damit zu tun, dass etwas zu etwas anderem hinzugefügt wird.

---

### aufhängen

> Heinz **hängt** seine Jacke an einem Garderobehaken **auf.**

Damit ist gemeint, dass Heinz seine Jacke so an dem Haken befestigt, dass sie, gezogen von der Schwerkraft, von dem Haken nach unten hängt. Jacke und Haken befinden sich nicht auf derselben Höhe, sondern untereinander. Das Gewicht der Jacke lastet zur Gänze an dem Haken. Der Zweck des Hakens ist es, dieses Gewicht vollständig zu tragen.

Auch dieses Verb wird in vielen verschiedenen anderen Bedeutungen verwendet (z.B. »Herr Schuster hat sich aufgehängt« = »Herr Schuster hat Selbstmord durch Erhängen verübt«) In allen diesen anderen Bedeutung spielt die Schwerkraft eine Rolle. Es wird beschrieben, dass sich etwas aufgrund der Schwerkraft unterhalb von etwas anderem befindet, wobei zwischen beiden eine Verbindung besteht. Ohne diese Verbindung würde der untere Teil herabfallen.

---

### hängen

Die beiden zuvor beschriebenen Verben (*anhängen* und *aufhängen*) beschreiben jeweils nur das Herstellen einer Verbindung. Sobald die Verbindung besteht, wird stattdessen das Verb *hängen* verwendet:

> Der Hund **hängt** an der Leine.
>   Die Wäsche **hängt** auf der Leine.

*Anhängen* und *aufhängen* beschreiben also einen Vorgang, *hängen* beschreibt hingegen einen Zustand.

Beachte, dass die Wörter »*an*« und »*auf*« in diesen beiden Beispielen keine Bestandteile eines trennbaren Verbs sind, sondern dass es sich hier um Präpositionen handelt. Das kann man an zwei Dingen erkennen:

1. Die beiden Bestandteile eines trennbaren Verbs stehen in einem Aussagesatz immer an der Position 2 und an der letzten Position eines Satzes. Eine *Prä*position steht immer *vor* dem Wort bzw. vor der Wortgruppe, auf welche(s) es sich bezieht (*prä* = *vor*), kann also niemals an der letzen Position stehen.
2. Wenn man eine Zeitform wählt, die mit einem Hilfsverb gebildet wird (z.B. Futur I), dann wird das Verb im Infinitiv verwendet (und rutscht dabei an die letzte Position des Satzes). Dann fallen die beiden Bestandteile eines trennbaren Verbs wieder zusammen und bilden ein einzelnes Wort. Eine Präposition bleibt aber in allen Zeitformen vom Verb getrennt.

Beispiele:

- **anhängen, aufhängen** (trennbare Verben; Vorgänge)

  - Präsens

    > Heinz **hängt** den Anhänger an sein Auto **an.**
    >   Heinz **hängt** seine Jacke an einem Garderobehaken **auf.**
    >   Erika **hängt** ihren Hund **an.**
    >   Manfred **hängt** die Wäsche **auf.**
  - Futur I

    > Heinz wird den Anhänger an sein Auto **anhängen.**
    >   Heinz wird seine Jacke an einem Garderobehaken **aufhängen.**
    >   Erika wird ihren Hund **anhängen.**
    >   Manfred wird die Wäsche **aufhängen.**
- **hängen an/auf etwas** (Verb + Präposition; Zustand)

  - Präsens

    > Der Anhänger **hängt** *an* dem Auto.
    >   Die Jacke **hängt** *auf* dem Haken.
    >   Der Hund **hängt** *an* der Leine.
    >   Die Wäsche **hängt** *auf* der Leine.
  - Futur I

    > Der Anhänger wird *an* dem Auto **hängen.**
    >   Die Jacke wird *auf* dem Haken **hängen.**
    >   Der Hund wird *an* der Leine **hängen.**
    >   Die Wäsche wird *auf* der Leine **hängen.**